# Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account

Tags: google-drive-api

By delegating domain-wide authority to the service account will increase the service account storage limitation from 5gb?(I am thinking that we can access domain user storage capacity)Is it right? Is there any other way to increase the storage capacity of service account?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service account is a concept used for authentication such that it can act on behalf of other users without the need to request permissions from them. So I doubt it can be treated like an actual Google account with storage quota and everything. If you want to use a single Google account for storage, then you can create a generic Google account in your domain and purchase extra drive storage if you want more than 5GB for that account. You can then get the service account to act on behalf this generic Google account.